# Прокручиваемый DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

При использовании `ScrollView` с `DrawerLayout`, выдает ошибку. Сам код выглядит так

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.eldos.callreport.TabsTogetherDrawerLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

А ошибку выдает такую

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:814)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Expert разве с абзацами не более читабельно.

Comment: @gcoder потому что есть элементы, которые не вмещаются в боковое меню

Comment: так и добавляйте элементы в scrollview или listview

Comment: @gcoder вы имеете ввиду что надо добавлять в scrollview только то что не вмещается? но мне так не нужно мне нужно чтобы он весь прокручивался

Comment: сделал неправильно, я пытался добавить тулбар в scrollView,
а  надо было только второй элемент drawerlayota закидывать в scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawerLayout может быть только корневым элементом. У вас же он лежит в LinearLayout, который лежит в ScrollView.

Comment: у меня сейчас корневой linearlaout, а Scrollview покрывает только второй элемент, то есть тот, который без тулбара